# Primefaces Schedule styclass and allday

Tags: styles, primefaces, schedule

I want to add the styclass and the allday variable to an event. Here's is the thing, The DefaultScheduleEvent does not have a method to be able to set both variables,

So if i choose to set the variable of allday i cannot change the color of the event shown in the schedule, but it shows by hours what i need to show; if I set the styleclass variable, i can change the colors, but the events are not by hours, so the appear as if each event took all day to be executed.

Is there a way can set this two variables, at the same time???

Thx

Answer (score 1):

DefaultScheduleEvent has a constructor in which you can set the style and a setter for you to set whether or not it is all day (as of 3.0-RC1 anyway). Here's how I have it:

```
evt = new DefaultScheduleEvent("My event", start, finish, "calendarButton");
evt.setAllDay(true);
evt.setEditable(false);
calendar.add(evt);
```

Then, on my CSS I have this for the style (the background bit is a bit annoying to get right):

```
.calendarButton, .calendarButton .fc-event-skin, .calendarButton a {
background-color: #aaaaaa;
border-color: gray;
}
```